# What's the best method for checking authentication and authorization by using nested master page

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, master-pages, multilingual

I'm implementing my website by using asp.net and C#.
I have my own membership system with roles, activities and users.

I'm using nested master page, Main.master is parent master page and `Sub.master` is child master page. My Login page is using `Sub.master` but user menu is in `Master.master`.

My question is Is there any solution to check authentication and authorization for all content page instead of doing this in each content page?

And also I no have idea for change culture of my website in this structure.

I've read about master page content page life cycle but I got confused. I don't know which method is better for authentication. I mean `Page_Init`, `Pre_Init`, `Page_Load` of parent master page child master page or content page.

I would appreciate it if you could give me some advice.